# Janitor broke my visual interface - Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, catalyst, ubuntu-tweak

yesterday a performed a couple of updates and after that i have executed Janitor (from within ubuntu-tweak) to cleanup (incl. everything, also old kernels) my system (Xubuntu 12.04.2, running on a recent Dell Inspiron 15R, dual boot with windows 8, hybrid graphics ATI7670). This turned out to be a bad mistake, when i power on the laptop and select Xubuntu from Grub i still do see the xubuntu loading screen, but after that i end up at a command line login (tty1).

My first idea was that i maybe somehow broke the kernel, so i decided to reinstall it - but now change. Next, i have checked some log files (syslog, kern.log, Xorg.0.log), the kern and sys logs do look ok, but the Xorg.0.log gave me some errors. Maybe i should add here that iam using the AMD catalyst driver (12.10.5) to control my hybrid graphics setup. The error messages looked as follows:

```
Screen 1 deleted because of no matching confg section
Unloadmodule "Intel"
Unloading intel
fglrx(0): Powerexpress: Integrated GPU is selected
fglrx(0): Powerexpress: cannot start '/usr/lib/fglrx' no such file or directory
```

I guess thats the problem, anyone any idea what to do? My next step would be to reinstall catalyst from the commandline (any suggestions how to that the best way?). Since iam relying on this laptop a lot for work i would appreciate any help.

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you indeed accidentally removed the proprietary AMD driver (fglrx in the log). Log in to your virtual terminal and execute `sudo jockey-text` from there to reinstall it. Then you should be good to go. If possible, please inform the developer of computer-janitor of this misbehavior.

What I did to resolve this even though I did not have an AMD card:

1. `fglrx` caught my attention
2. `apt-cache search fglrx` yielded `jockey-gtk`. It appeared already installed.
3. Since you have no graphics I tried jockey-<kbd>Tab</kbd> on the terminal
4. `jockey-text` was autocompleted and executed but did not find any additional (read: proprietary) drivers. Assumed this would fix if there were any.